# PHP multidimensional array loop through second dimension

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

how do i loop this kind of array?

```
$arr = array (
  "aa"=>array("apple","orange"),
  "bb"=>array("373","22"),
  "cc"=>array("t0","h0"),
  "dd"=>array("1","0")
);
```

I want to loop through the column of each item.
e.g.: i want to display ('apple','373','t0','1') at the first loop and ('orange','22','h0','0') at the last loop. thanks

Comment: Using what code? Can you post what you already have and where it fails/what its actual output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are assuming that all the arrays inside the main array are the same size in this example.

```
$arr = array (
  "aa"=>array("apple","orange"),
  "bb"=>array("373","22"),
  "cc"=>array("t0","h0"),
  "dd"=>array("1","0")
);

for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($arr["aa"]); $i++)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item)
    {
        echo($item[$i]);
    }
    echo ' - ';
}
```

**Output:** (obviously you can do any necessary formatting you need such as new lines or commas)

apple373t01 - orange22h00 -

Comment: `sizeof("aa")` won't work

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  Rushed through the code a bit too quickly haha.  it actually works perfect with the incorrect code due to the size of the string "aa" being the correct length, but obviously thats not the right way to do things.  Got my code example updated

Comment: Would throw a "_Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable_" though